# UIWebView and interface orientation

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, youtube

I'm creating a simple tab bar app for my YouTube channel. I have tabs for Twitter, Facebook and other stuff, but my last one is a YouTube channel. I just did a standard `UIWebView` with the website and it's like you're on the mobile platform in Safari like I want, but when you play a video it only works in portrait view and I have tried a few things like changing the code so it is

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: 
  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

But that sadly makes the whole tab bar application landscape and that isn't what I'm looking to do. I honestly have spent hours upon hours trying new things and I literally am having no progress and I am getting very frustrated. I hope this helps, thank you. And just in case I was confusing before I would like to just make the Youtube videos in the `UIWebView` landscape and that is it. Thanks again. Also if this isn't possible could I get maybe some direction on how to implement a youtube API into a tab bar app...?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you gone into app summary and clicked to available orientations?
2. Are You running it in the simulated if you go to the menu at the top of your mac and go to hardware then click the rotation you would like or just type Command-(then the direction on your arrow keys such as -->)

Other than that I have no clue.